# Is there a way to 'see under the hood' of a file without having to open it in program that supports it?

Tags: file-conversion

I have some files that are .zfab and .u3ma. They are fabrics for 3D garment rendering called CLO and Browsewear. These two companies also specializes in testing physical fabrics which is the part I'm interested in. However they are adamant they want pack them into their own fileformat which only works when using their own software.

I'm trying to find another way to use their services without manually have to first load the files into the respective software and then copy paste all the data into a more flexible format like a JSON.

Is it anyway possible to force open these file formats to see if theres a way to export the data I need?

Comment: If you open the terminal application and type the word `file` and then drag one each of the sample files into that window (then press return) - what do the results of this file fingerprinting tool say?

Comment: I've found that, often, just opening a file in a text editor (I use BBEdit) will reveal a lot about the file. Hex editors are also helpful for this.

Comment: @bmike one give me - it worked - one showed me 'data', but the other said "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract" and I tried to unzip it and low and behold it was all there neatly with a JSON and everything

Answer (score 0):

Plain text editors like TextEdit, Sublime Text (unlimited free trial), BBEdit, etc. can show the contents in text format. If the file is JSON or XML, for example, it will be readable with the built in TextEdit program.

If the application is a binary format, you will need a hex editor. Hex Fiend is available for free on the Mac App Store and provides the raw binary data on the left next to the interpreted text data on the right.

Comment: I tried with the text editor one worked the other not...